# Javascript: replace a highlighted string in text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highilght a string/text in textarea and then wrap it around a custom  tag.

I can easily now get the highlighted text and I can wrap it around the  tag and alert() it but I cannot replace it inside the textarea.

This is my working FIDDLE(https://jsfiddle.net/dftLu6ax/)

And this is my Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$('#showSelected').on('click', function(){

function getInputSelection(elem){
 if(typeof elem != "undefined"){
  s=elem[0].selectionStart;
  e=elem[0].selectionEnd;
  return elem.val().substring(s, e);
 }else{
  return '';
 }
}
var text = getInputSelection($("#details"));  

var link = prompt("Please enter your URL", "");
    if (link != null) {

    var str = document.getElementById("details").value;
    var res = str.replace(text, "<a onclick='somevariable goes here' href=''>"+text+"</a>");

    alert(res);

        /*document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";*/
    }

});
```

and my simple HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="showSelected" value="Insert Link">


    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="details" name="details"></textarea>
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `$("#details").val(res);`. This will replace the selected text in textarea with the one you are displaying in alert

Comment: @Akshay, I'm not trying to replace the entire text in textarea with the one I just highlighted!

Answer (score 3):

Because you get the text inside the textarea with:

```
document.getElementById("details").value
```

You may use the same to set the updated value:

```js
function getInputSelection(elem){
  if(typeof elem != "undefined"){
    s=elem[0].selectionStart;
    e=elem[0].selectionEnd;
    return elem.val().substring(s, e);
  }else{
    return '';
  }
}
$(function () {
  $('#showSelected').on('click', function(){
    var text = getInputSelection($("#details"));
    var link = prompt("Please enter your URL", "");
    if (link != null) {
      var str = document.getElementById("details").value;
      var res = str.replace(text, "<a onclick='somevariable goes here' href=''>"+text+"</a>");
      
      //THIS LINE
      document.getElementById("details").value = res;
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" id="showSelected" value="Insert Link">

<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="details" name="details"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#details").val(res)` for that

```
$('#showSelected').on('click', function(){

function getInputSelection(elem){
 if(typeof elem != "undefined"){
  s=elem[0].selectionStart;
  e=elem[0].selectionEnd;
  return elem.val().substring(s, e);
 }else{
  return '';
 }
}
var text = getInputSelection($("#details"));  

var link = prompt("Please enter your URL", "");
    if (link != null) {

    var str = document.getElementById("details").value;
    var res = str.replace(text, "<a onclick='somevariable goes here' href=''>"+text+"</a>");
$("#details").val(res);
        /*document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";*/
    }

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dftLu6ax/3/